Virtual Template Best Practice when Realization has small cardinality
I have the virtual template problem, i.e.:
class Base{
public:
    // template<bool flag> virtual void eval()=0; // line A
};

class Derived: public Base{
public:
    template<bool flag> void eval(){ std::cout<<"eval<"<<flag<<">();\n"; }
};

int main(){
    Derived d;
    Base& br = d;
    br.eval<true>();
}

Here, incommenting of line A fails due to standard violation, whereas outcommenting results in unknown function reference from POV of br.
Possible Fix
Because the template realization has very small cardinality (i.e. 2, in words: "two"), the following fix is possible:
#include<iostream>

class Base{
    virtual void eval_impl(std::integral_constant<bool,true >)=0;
    virtual void eval_impl(std::integral_constant<bool,false>)=0;
public:
    template<bool flag> void eval(){ eval_impl(std::integral_constant<bool,flag>{} ); }
};

class Derived: public Base{
    // outcommeted wont work due to distinct signature from template instantiation
    // template<bool flag> void eval_impl(std::integral_constant<bool,flag>){ eval<flag>(); }
    void eval_impl(std::integral_constant<bool,true >){ eval<true >(); }
    void eval_impl(std::integral_constant<bool,false>){ eval<false>(); }
public:
    template<bool flag> void eval(){ std::cout<<"eval<"<<flag<<">();\n";  } // this is given
};

int main(){
    Derived d;          // may not be templated
    Base& br = d;       // may not be templated
    br.eval<true >();   // true  realization must exist
    br.eval<false>();   // false realization must exist
}

Disadvantages:

at least 70% of all characters are boilerplate
needs two lines of boilerplate per element of the cardinality group (here: true and false)
all realizations are always assembled (dead compiled code)
barely readable
necessitates instantiations of integral_constants without their actual need.

Question
Is there a better practice, under the following constraints:

the signature of Base and Derived remains unaltered
the signature of Derived::eval remains unaltered
references of Base on Derived can call eval<true> and eval<false>


Why is it important that the signatures of Base and Derived remains unaltered? It's not like this is part of an ABI that needs to be stable, right?

virtual void eval_true(); virtual void eval_false(); would do the job, is clear (except naming ;-) ), is simple, is short to type.

@TedLyngmo .. because my classes already have like ten other template arguments and these are set by a template metaprogramming wrapper and it is already awful so I did not want to add further complication to it. I know that is not a good reason, so ... I did not tell :D

@Jarod42 true. I started with integral_constant because I thought the extra lines in Derived for eval_impl could be reduced to one line in total; however, the template signature does not replace the explicit signatures -.-

@user23311233 To not make it even more messy, why not just make eval into a regular virtual member function that takes a bool argument, like this?

pure virtual template doesn't make sense. How do you expect vtable is instantiated in such cases? Why you making this so complicated? Why not just two virtual methods with distinct names and some helper template function which calls respective function depending on template argument? Anyway this is still over-engineering and question clearly suffers from XY problem.

"all realizations are always assembled (dead compiled code)" That's how  virtual functions work. When the called function is determined at runtime, all the functions must always be there. Like, if you only call eval<true> for all the classes, what if next year a Derived46 starts calling eval<false>? Should that modify the vtable for all existing classes? No, it cannot.
